How to consider M\\S as a sutured manifold?
I'm reading guts in sutured decompositions and the thurston norm by Agol and Zhang. Now $M$ is a compact 3-manifold and $S$ is a properly norm-minimizing surface in M. $M\backslash\backslash S$ means $M\backslash \eta(S)$ where $\eta(S)$ is the tubular neighbourhood of $S$. I don't know how to "consider $M\backslash\backslash S$ as a sutured manifold, as I don't know what the suture is.

See section $6$ here.

Thanks a lot! This is really helpful.
